# Why is this code produce a -10 when i try to rerun the program?

Tags: c

This code seems to work as it should until I go to rerun the program. It still seems to work but the beginning of the line to input the next set of text has a '-10.' I'm not positive but the problem looks to be in the printf from what I can tell. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you!
Sorry folks... as per a request to explain what this program is supposed to do. It is supposed to take input until the '#' sign and then print it with its corresponding ASCII numeric code with it in blocks of 8. Hope that makes sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define COUNT 8

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char ch;
    int charcount;

    while((ch = getchar()) != '#')
    {
        putchar(ch);
        printf("-%d ", ch);

        charcount++;
        if(charcount % COUNT == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit and add testing input, expected output and output you received. Also, learning to use a debugger is highly recommended.

Comment: Delete `printf("-%d ", ch);`

Comment: It is printing the ordinal value of a newline `\n` character which has ASCII value 10.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you. Is there a way to display the character-numeric pairs without a printf?

Comment: Yes you just have to convert ch to a string representing the value, but you can simply print the pair with `printf("%c-%d",ch,ch);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 is the value for a new linefeed ('\n', enter key). If you want to filter out your enter key, simply add this right after the loop starts:

```
if(ch == '\n') continue;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm in the chapter of if else if else continue and break. You fixed my problem and with those other answers i now understand why it was spittig out 10.

Comment: Thank you CRoemheld

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf` statement

```
printf("-%d ", ch);
```

prints a minus sign and then the decimal code for `linefeed`.  You pressed Enter, didn't you?

Comment: Indeed, I believe that's what OP did.

Comment: Yes I did. CRoemheld has the fix. Is there another way to display the numeric value alongside the letters the user inputs without the printf?